# SQL : select values between multiple ranges

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like the one below...

```
ID    Price
==== ======
1    1000
2    2000
3    4000
4    5000
```

Now I need a query to select values `between 500 and 1500` And `between 2500 and 4500`. i.e. like using two between in a single select query...

is it possible?

output should be:

```
ID    Price
==== ======
1    1000
3    4000
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
select id, price
from tablename
where price between 500 and 1500
   or price between 2500 and 4500
```

Comment: What if the ranges are coming from a table? So it is possible to have dynamic query for multiple ranges?

Comment: @Aryo, you can probably do a JOIN and put the conditions in the ON clause. Ask a question and put the link here, and I'll take a look at it.